# querydsl - remove whitespace in the middle of a COLUMN

Tags: replace, querydsl, removing-whitespace

Is there a way to do this query in querydsl?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE replace(column_name, ' ', '') = 'someValue';
```

The `StringPath` from the `QClass` has no .`replace()` function and it's necessary for some characters (specifically, spaces in the *middle*) to be removed from `column_name` before testing it with `someValue`.

Sample `column_name` contents: `ABC, DEF, AB *`

If `someValue` is `ABC`, `ABC` and `AB*` should appear.

Comment: Do you use Querydsl with JPA or JDBC?

Comment: @TimoWestkämper We're using JDBC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can express the replace invocation via

```
Expressions.stringTemplate("replace({0},'  ','')", columnPath)
```

Comment: This is great! I didn't know this was possible. This is the final predicate: 


`BooleanBuilder b = new BooleanBuilder().andAnyOf(

 Expressions.stringTemplate("replace({0},' ','')", columnPath).like(someValue.substring(0,2)  
Expressions.stringTemplate("replace({0},' ','')", columnPath).like(someValue.substring(0,1) + "*"),

 columnPath.eq(StringUtils.replaceWildcardChar(someValue)));`



Thanks.

Comment: Hello, how we can do this if I want to replace space, dash and quote char from columnValue?